# CRM 2013 Sharepoint Integration

Tags: sharepoint, integration, dynamics-crm-2013, create-directory

I'm out of answers here.

I have an online build of CRM 2013 which  is integrated with SharePoint.
I can view, upload and edit files for an example Organisation (OrgA) but there is another  for which I can't (OrgB). OrgA has a  document location setup but OrgB does not so I used the Add Document Location wizard to create a folder, but it hangs at the creation part. I have browsed the ShapePoint client and the folder has not been created.

I have looked in Document Management Settings and the entity I want is ticked so I clicked next and I can see that the SharePoint URL is valid but I get the following warning

"Microsoft Dynamics CRM List component is not installed.

Install the List component to enable SharePoint to automatically create a hierarchical folder structure on SharePoint for Microsoft Dynamics CRM records. The List component also enables you to get the appearance and behavior of a Microsoft Dynamics CRM list."

If there is a missing component then how did my predecessor (this is only my 2nd day) set up the integration for OrgA and if it is not needed, why can't I create the folder for OrgB through CRM?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One of the limitations of CRM SharePoint integration is the ability integrate multiple CRM organizations with a SharePoint application in the same farm.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn949332.aspx)

> If you use Microsoft SharePoint 2013, for each SharePoint farm, only
>   one Microsoft Dynamics CRM organization can be configured for
>   server-based integration.

So in your case it is either OrgA or OrgB, can't have both integrated to the same SharePoint server.

Comment: I may not have been clear. Organisation is an entity (think of it as customer)